# Swift Filter other arrays based on another Bool array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, flatmap

I have an array of Bools and want to edit an array of Scores and an array of Dates for the values that are False. I can't get to it. I thought of getting elements that are false and using that array to remove those elements from the score array but I can imagine there is a direct way of doing it.

```
let hbiCompleteArray = [true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, false]

let hbiScoreArray = [12, 12, 12, 12, 3, 13, 13, 2, 2]
```

I want an array of completeHbiScores = [12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13]

Comment: Consider to use **one** array of a custom struct for the model rather than multiple arrays.

Comment: OOO that sounds super cool how can I do that?

Comment: [Swift Language Guide: Classes and Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *have to* use two arrays, you can solve this with `zip`, `filter` and `map` like this:

```
let hbiCompleteArray = [true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, false]
let hbiScoreArray = [12, 12, 12, 12, 3, 13, 13, 2, 2]

let result = zip(hbiCompleteArray, hbiScoreArray).filter { $0.0 }.map { $1 }
print(result)
```

Gives:

> [12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13]

Explanation: the `zip` interleaves the two arrays (makes an array of `(Bool, Int)` tuples), then `filter { $0.0 }` only keeps the `true` booleans, then the `map` only keeps the Int values.

Comment: This is a good and fairly simple way to do it if the arrays aren't overly large. The only issue is that each of these operations iterate through the arrays and so it can bog down on large arrays. Is it enough to optimize? That's up to you to decide, certainly don't go for a more complicated solution unless testing shows this to be too slow for your needs.

Comment: never seen `zip` before!

Comment: @Honey it creates a [Zip2Sequence](http://sketchytech.blogspot.co.uk/2016/03/swift-sticking-together-with.html) instance.

Comment: @ColGraff It's true that it iterates multiple times, *but* I think it's not an issue, not even a concern, here. We can guess that OP won't have billions of scores in their array - also, the nature of Zip2Sequence (not an actual array) and the fact that filter/map are optimized (buffers, copy-on-write, compiler optimizations, etc) makes me say that it's really ok here. :)

Comment: I agree that it's probably not a concern and switching to another solution without testing for bottlenecks is definitely premature optimization. Use this solution for its simplicity and clarity, if testing shows it's a bottleneck then optimize it. That should be a guideline for most software development!

Comment: @ColGraff Couldn't agree more. 

Comment: Note that you could also use `flatMap` instead of `filter` and `map`, e.g `let result = zip(hbiCompleteArray, hbiScoreArray).flatMap {$0 ? $1 : nil}` :)

Comment: @Hamish Nice one!

Comment: Actually the arrays can get quite large as I will present a graph of the data for 7 days, 30 days and 90 days. For 90 days then it can be 90 x every days readings taken. That could be an array of say up to 2500 elements. I do not know if that would be a concern for this solution. It is amazing though.

Comment: Works well and is really elegant. Trying got use the same method to return an array of dates now. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The comment from vadian is very important here. You should not have multiple arrays this way. Create a struct that holds the data:

```
struct Score {
    let isComplete: Bool
    let finalScore: Int
}
```

You can then add a Date or whatever other fields you currently have parallel arrays for. Then your data looks like:

```
let scores = [
    Score(isComplete: true, finalScore: 12),
    Score(isComplete: true, finalScore: 12),
    Score(isComplete: true, finalScore: 12),
    Score(isComplete: true, finalScore: 12),
    Score(isComplete: false, finalScore: 3),
    Score(isComplete: true, finalScore: 13),
    Score(isComplete: true, finalScore: 13),
    Score(isComplete: false, finalScore: 2),
    Score(isComplete: false, finalScore: 2),
]
```

And getting complete ones is simple by filtering

```
let completeScores = scores.filter { $0.isComplete }
```

Of course if you wanted just the final scores as an array, you can map down to that:

```
let finalCompleteScores = completeScores.map { $0.finalScore }
```

This is how you should be thinking about your data, rather than as a bunch of arrays you have to keep in sync.

Comment: This is certainly the optimal solution if you can put your data into a single struct, it usually results in cleaner and easier to maintain code. If you have to have two arrays for other design reasons then the other solutions might work better.

Comment: I like this solution as I can also add the date of the score. I can then use the date/ score for the graph. I will try it later.

Answer (score 1):

Agree that parallel arrays approach isn't the best structure to use for your code but an alternative to filter and map used by Eric is reduce:

```
let completeHbiScores = zip(hbiCompleteArray, hbiScoreArray).reduce([Int]()){
    (newArray,zippedArray) in
    if zippedArray.0 {
        return newArray + [zippedArray.1]
    }
    else {
        return newArray
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another fairly easy way to do this that iterates only once through your arrays is this:

```
let hbiCompleteArray = [true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, false]
let hbiScoreArray = [12, 12, 12, 12, 3, 13, 13, 2, 2]
var completeHbiScores = [Int]()

for score in hbiScoreArray.enumerated() {
  // break out of the loop if we're at the end of hbiCompleteArray
  // assuming that no value means default to false
  guard score.offset < hbiCompleteArray.count else { break }

  // go to the next score if the current element is false
  guard hbiCompleteArray[score.offset] else { continue }

  completeHbiScores.append(score.element)
}
```